# How to call php into wordpress page ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am making some page which will have some sorted content from databse. A have already made sorting php and i need to call it propably by button, and i need taht php output to be written to some div which is already on page. is it possible?

sorting.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY added ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div class='something'>";
  echo "<a href='$row[link]'>";
  echo "<img src='$row[img]' height='125' width='125'/>";
  echo "<p>$row[name]</p></a></div>";
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

Every type of sort or filter will be handled by different php.
Is this good way how to make this kind of page? or is there some easier and better way? 
And one more thing. Is it possible to have some transitions when different type of filter is selected? I would like something like this: [quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can include jQuery on your page, it has a shorthand method for doing exactly that: [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Your final javascript might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#searchButton").bind('click', function() {
        $("#resultsDiv").load(
            'http://mysite.com/sorting.php',
            { // parameters, in object literal format
               sortDir: 'asc',
               sortCol: 'lastname'
               // etc.
            }
        );
    });

});
```

Where you substitute mysite.com, searchButton, and resultsDiv with the real information for your site/markup. You can also get the sort params from page elements with jquery selectors like so: `$("#sortDir").val()` - assumes a text box, text area or select box. There are other ways to retrieve checkboxes and radio buttons, assuming your form uses them. To answer your other questions:

> 1) Every type of sort or filter will be handled by different php. Is this good way how to make this kind of page? or is there some easier and better way?

It's not unreasonable for a small number. Not accepting any arguments on the server is one way to make sure you don't ever allow malicious input. It tends to get unwieldy when you need to change a table name or the columns you're selecting and have to modify every file. You also need to realize that if you allow combinations of filters and sorts, you're talking about supporting the intersection of them. If you have 3 filters and 4 sorts, that's 12 combinations. If you want to add another sort and another filter, you have to add 4 new pages for filters and 5 new pages for sorts - and it gets worse every time.

Most people would go the route of having all data go to the same page and have only that page be responsible for validating user input, formulating the query, and returning the results. This paradigm commonly called [DRY for Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). But if you are accepting user input, you need to be very careful about [validating it](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=validate%20user%20input%20php) (on the server side! [Don't trust user input](https://www.google.com/search?q=don%27t%20trust%20user%20input)!) and not allowing e.g. a [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) [attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

> 2) And one more thing. Is it possible to have some transitions when different type of filter is selected? I would like something like this: quicksand

That particular animation is very complex. They are running a difference between the icons to be shown for each page and programmatically customizing which icons to shrink out, explode in, move etc. etc. I could go into more detail about how to do it yourself...

But your know what? It's a plugin, compatible with jQuery 1.3+ and licensed under MIT & GPLv2, so you should have no problems incorporating it into your site. Check the [docs](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html) and take a stab at it yourself. I don't see anything inherently incompatible with sorting the type of markup you're returning. I do notice that their example is using `li` tags for sorting and your example return is using `div`. But that shouldn't be a major hangup, and if it is, just return `li`s instead. When you run into problems using it, post another question, tag it appropriately and be prepared to post everything you've tried in that regard.

Comment: thanks for help, it works accept your .load() is missing a closing parenthesis, but thats detail. one more thing. I have no idea what for are those sortDir and sortCol. could you please explain those to me?

Comment: Corrected the tyop, sorry about that. sortDir and sortCol are just example parameters. You mentioned having multiple pages for different sorts and filters. The options I pass are examples for passing to the same page. To go back to your example code, sortCol would be 'added' (because that's what you ORDER BY) and sortDir would be 'ASC' (because that's the direction your example sorts (orders)).

Comment: yes that i thought too and tried, but it dont work. i changed it to sortDir: 'asc', sortCol: 'added' and nothing happens. to chceck if this works i tried it to sort by added, and name asc and desc, but nothing changes.

Comment: I'm sure you will need to modify your php code to accept those parameters. That's an entirely different question.