# mySQL database sorting with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sorting

I just stuck on some problem with my code. Could anybody please tell me what i have done wrong?

html:

```
<button type="button" id="searchbutton">Click Me!</button> 
<div id="resultsdiv"></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#searchbutton").bind('click', function() {
        $("#resultsdiv").load(
            'http://profithing.com/wp-content/php/sorting.php',
            { // parameters, in object literal format
               sortDir: 'asc',
               sortCol: 'name'
               // etc.
            }
    });

});
```

php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "login", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY added ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div class='something'>";
  echo "<a href='$row[link]'>";
  echo "<img src='$row[img]' height='125' width='125'/>";
  echo "<p>$row[name]</p></a></div>";
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/profithing/hg9CY/)
i think that my php is ok, there must be some problem in calling it.
Thanks for help.

EDIT: added php code

Comment: what's it (not)doing? "some problem" doesn't help us at all.

Comment: I think your problem is in PHP. And as commented above, what is the exact problem?

Comment: it s not posting anything after button click

Comment: Can you show the php? There is really no way to help unless there is more info

Comment: check this http://profithing.com/wp-content/php/sorting.php to see what it should post

Comment: At the very least, your .load() is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: You mention MySQL in the title but you show us only html and JavaScript. My apologies but I'm not seeing the connection. Is the content that you are loading with `.load` coming from a MySQL. The title is not representative of the problem. This does not appear to have anything to do with MySQL.

Comment: Checking your JavaScript console for syntax (or other) errors is the very first thing you should do.

Comment: Thank for advice i am realy no pro in this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing your statements incorrectly (missing a `);`). Please see below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchbutton").bind('click', function() {
        $("#resultsdiv").load(
            'http://profithing.com/wp-content/php/sorting.php',
            { // parameters, in object literal format
               sortDir: 'asc',
               sortCol: 'name'
               // etc.
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: ok it works. one more question. do you know how that sortDir and sortCol works? thanks for help

Comment: No problem... sorry no I don't.. I've had a quick search but I can't find any reference to `sortDir` and `sortCol`... can I ask where you have found this?

Comment: sure. it was advice from this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073643/how-to-call-php-into-wordpress-page-ajax

Comment: ok I'm not too sure what @PatrickM is talking about here. So it may be worth replying to his comment to ask for further help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `);` after your load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#searchbutton").bind('click', function() {
        $("#resultsdiv").load(
            'http://profithing.com/wp-content/php/sorting.php',
            { // parameters, in object literal format
               sortDir: 'asc',
               sortCol: 'name'
               // etc.
            }); // you forgot the ); here.
    });

});
```

also the fiddle wont work because of the same origin policy... [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)